# How to make two vertices to have a certain bearing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vertices, bearing

I have a shapefile in QGIS which was hand-drawn and I want to align the N/S and E/W lines to true N/S and E/W, is there a way to select the two vertices of the line and make one/both move to make the line a specific bearing?

Comment: Do you want to rotate the lines ? Better if you show an image with expected result.

Comment: Can you post a pic of what the data looks like? Is it just grid lines that need straightened?